Generate a record per date from another table date range
Good morning,
I am trying to generate a table in snowflake that will add a record for each date within a date range.  I want to get the date range from start and end date and put a record in the new table with each corresponding date in between.
    WITH CTEDATA (
select
'123' as MemberID,
'01/01/2024' as start_date,
'01/05/2024' as end_date
), CTEDATE as (
select 
DT.DATE,
/*
What do I put here
*/
from DATETABLE DT
/*
What do I put here  DATE TABLE HAS 30 day in it.
*/
/*
DATE        MEMBER_ID   StartDate   EndDate
01/01/2024  123         01/01/2024  01/05/2024
01/02/2024  123         01/01/2024  01/05/2024
01/03/2024  123         01/01/2024  01/05/2024
01/04/2024  123         01/01/2024  01/05/2024
01/05/2024  123         01/01/2024  01/05/2024
*/


with ctedata as (
    select
        '123' as MemberID,
        to_date('01/01/2024', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as start_date,
        to_date('01/05/2024', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as end_date,
        datediff("days", start_date, end_date) + 1 range
)
  select
      to_varchar(dateadd("days", a.index, ctedata.start_date), 'mm/dd/yyyy') date,
      ctedata.MemberID,
      to_varchar(ctedata.start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') start_date,
      to_varchar(ctedata.end_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') end_date
  from ctedata,
  lateral flatten(array_generate_range(0, ctedata.range)) a;




DATE
MEMBERID
START_DATE
END_DATE




01/01/2024
123
01/01/2024
01/05/2024


01/02/2024
123
01/01/2024
01/05/2024


01/03/2024
123
01/01/2024
01/05/2024


01/04/2024
123
01/01/2024
01/05/2024


01/05/2024
123
01/01/2024
01/05/2024



